# Get HTML formatted XML data using JSONP jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xml, jsonp

I'm trying to use jsonp to get xml data like this:

```
$.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/1111?report=xml&format=text",
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      success: function(json) {
        console.log(json);
      },
      error: function(e) {
         console.log(e.message);
      }
    });
```

However, the website seems to not return an xml document, but instead HTML formatted xml.
See this http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/1111?report=xml&format=text

So I get an error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`

Any pointers?

Comment: If the server does not support JSONP, you can't force it to do so.

Answer (score 0):

The link you have is a Retrieve PubMed Citations link.  The link was made more for creating links than using it as a web service.  Details - http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK3862/

The do have some SOAP services - http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK43082/